# Mysql - Contar valores diferentes de um mesmo campo

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
Tabela partidas
+----+----------+------+---------------------+
| id | name     | win  | date                |
+----+----------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | Fulano   | Y    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | Fulano   | Y    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  3 | Fulano   | Y    | 2014-01-02 00:00:00 |
|  4 | Fulano   | Y    | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 |
|  5 | Fulano   | N    | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 |
|  6 | Beltrano | N    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  7 | Beltrano | N    | 2014-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  8 | Beltrano | N    | 2014-01-02 00:00:00 |
|  9 | Beltrano | Y    | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 10 | Cicrano  | Y    | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 |
| 11 | Cicrano  | N    | 2014-01-03 00:00:00 |
+----+----------+------+---------------------+
```

Gostaria de fazer algo parecido como:

```
SELECT name, count(win='Y') AS vitorias, count(win='N') AS derrotas
FROM partidas GROUP BY name;
```

Obviamente obtenho uma resposta indesejada, devido ao count não reconhecer o comando que inventei:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| name     | vitorias | derrotas |
+----------+----------+----------+
| Beltrano |        4 |        4 |
| Cicrano  |        2 |        2 |
| Fulano   |        5 |        5 |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

Alguém poderia ajudar a obter a resposta correta?

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer com o SUM():

```
SELECT name, sum(win='Y') AS vitorias, sum(win='N') AS derrotas
FROM partidas GROUP BY name;
```

**Ex:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]